# Image float Lyx

Tags: floats, lyx

I have an image float in Lyx as per below:

[image]

However, when exporting to pdf it is showing on the top of the page instead continuing with the rest of the documents, (refer to below image)

[image]

Anyone know how i can solve this please?

Comment: specifying that a figure floats means that the system can move it to the top of a page to help with page breaking so it sounds as if the document is working as expected

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Is there a way to avoid this as I need the float to continue with my documentation?

Comment: Go in the settings of the float and set to "Here definitely".

Comment: I don't use lynx so i'll leave someone else to answer, but presumably you can include an image without declaring it to be a float, note however that images are normally floated for a reason; if your text falls near the bottom of the page the image will not fit, so the traditional way to typeset figures is allow them to move and always refer to them via their caption number

Comment: You are saying "I need the float not to float" it's _called_ a float because it floats to the top of a page....